# Using GenerateBootstrapper class in c# code to generate bootstrappers programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is there any way I can use [GenerateBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx) class in c# code to generate bootstrappers programmatically? Has anyone tried this before?